Is there a Kotlin extension function for converting Multiple Sql tables Join results into a multi level List?
I have 3 tables in SQL database with foreign key references. I combined these 3 tables using INNER JOIN and the result keep it as List in my Kotlin application. As we know, the parent table has repeated values with matching rows of other tables. I am planning to create a multi(3) level list to supply in api as JSON result. Anyone tried Kotlin extension function for this purpose?
My Category.json Format:
[
  {
    "id": "kategorie1",
    "caption": "A",
    "features": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A1",
        "rotation": "0",
        "schedules": [
          {
            "id": 10,
            "time": "10 AM"
          },
          {
            "id": 11,
            "time": "12 AM"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "A2",
        "rotation": "0",
        "schedules": [
          {
            "id": 12,
            "time": "10 AM"
          },
          {
            "id": 13,
            "time": "12 AM"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "kategorie2",
    "caption": "B",
    "features": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "B1",
        "rotation": "0",
        "schedules": [
          {
            "id": 21,
            "time": "10 AM"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "B2",
        "rotation": "0",
        "schedules": [
          {
            "id": 23,
            "time": "10 AM"
          },
          {
            "id": 25,
            "time": "12 AM"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

And kotlin class using coroutine Flow implementation using multiple collect / group by extensions:
data class Category(
    val id: Long,
    val caption: String,
    val features: List<Feature>,
)

data class Feature(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val rotation: String,
    val schedules: List<Schedule>,
)

data class Schedule(
    val id: Long,
    val time: String,
)

Edited on Nov 06, 2024:-
I have to get sql inner join result as a list in kotlin. But it should be formated like nested multi level list to supply in api result as mentioned above (json format).
See my DB Schema:
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `caption` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `caption`) VALUES
    (1, 'kategorie1'),
    (2, 'kategorie2');

CREATE TABLE `feature` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rotation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_feature_category` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_feature_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO `feature` (`id`, `name`, `rotation`, `category_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'A1', '0', 1),
    (2, 'A2', '0', 1),
    (3, 'B1', '0', 2),
    (4, 'B2', '0', 2);


CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_schedule_feature` (`feature_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_schedule_feature` FOREIGN KEY (`feature_id`) REFERENCES `feature` (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO `schedule` (`id`, `time`, `feature_id`) VALUES
    (10, '10 AM', 1),
    (11, '12 AM', 1),
    (12, '10 AM', 2),
    (13, '12 AM', 2),
    (21, '10 AM', 3),
    (23, '10 AM', 4),
    (25, '12 AM', 4);

It's inner join query :-
SELECT * FROM category c INNER JOIN feature f ON f.category_id=c.id INNER JOIN schedules s ON s.feature_id = f.id; 

And corresponding inner join result as kotlin list :-
listOf(Result(id = 1, caption = "kategorie1", name = "A1", rotation = "0", time = "10 AM"),
        Result(id = 1, caption = "kategorie1", name = "A1", rotation = "0", time = "12 AM"),
        Result(id = 1, caption = "kategorie1", name = "A2", rotation = "0", time = "10 AM"),
        Result(id = 1, caption = "kategorie1", name = "A2", rotation = "0", time = "12 AM"),
        Result(id = 2, caption = "kategorie2", name = "B1", rotation = "0", time = "10 AM"),
        Result(id = 2, caption = "kategorie2", name = "B2", rotation = "0", time = "10 AM"),
        Result(id = 2, caption = "kategorie2", name = "B2", rotation = "0", time = "12 AM"))

I have to convert the above list as nested list like below  :-
listOf(
    Category(id = 1, caption = "kategorie1", features = listOf(
        Feature(id = 1, name = "A1", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 10, time = "10 AM"), Schedule(id = 11, time = "12 AM"))),
        Feature(id = 2, name = "A2", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 12, time = "10 AM"), Schedule(id = 13, time = "12 AM"))),
    )),
    Category(id = 2, caption = "kategorie2", features = listOf(
        Feature(id = 3, name = "B1", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 21, time = "10 AM"))),
        Feature(id = 4, name = "B2", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 23, time = "10 AM"), Schedule(id = 25, time = "12 AM"))),
    )),
)

I am fetching the data from db tables and keep it in Kotlin Coroutine Flow. I have tried to construct the nested list from it using collect with group by options.
results.collect { result: Result ->    
            val schedules = mutableMapOf<Long, MutableList<Schedules>>()
            val feature = mutableMapOf<Long, MutableList<Feature>>()
            val category = mutableMapOf<Long, MutableList<Category>>()
                        
            schedules.getOrPut(result.scheduleId!!) { mutableListOf() } += Schedules(result.scheduleId, result.time)
            feature.getOrPut(result.featureId) { mutableListOf() } += Feature(result.featureId, result.name, result.rotation, Schedules[result.scheduleId])
            category.getOrPut(result.categoryId) { mutableListOf() } += Category(result.categoryId, result.caption, dev[result.categoryId])
        }
        
        print("Nested list: $category")

No hope to achieve the nested list from inner join result list. Please help.

Can you clarify what you are actually asking? Do you just want to know how to create the JSON from a List<Root2>? And what is a "multi(3) level list"? Can you [edit] the question and provide an example?

I have to convert Flow to DTO list for multi level JSON.

So, to summarize: You want to create the given JSON from an object you have. If that is the case then please [edit] your question and remove everything that isn't needed for that (like the database structure, that has nothing to do with the question) and instead provide the data structure that you want to convert to JSON. As I see it that is the type Result after your edit. And finally, please also describe why my answer doesn't help you, that is, what else you need to know to solve your problem.

Assuming you just want to convert a List<Root2> to JSON you can use the official serialization support of Kotlin, from the library kotlinx.serialization. Follow the instructions of the documentation to set it up or use the short summary I added at the end of the answer.
Once set up, the usage of the library is very simple. Just add the @Serializable annotation to the three data classes involved. Then, assuming you have a val list: List<Root2> somewhere you can simply convert it to JSON like this:
val json: String = Json.encodeToString(list)

That's it, you can now return the json string as your API result. It has the same format as the example JSON from your question, just without line breaks and indentations (which you probably do not even want in the first place in your API response).
There are also a lot of customizaion options available should the need arise. See the linked documentation above.
For example, to create the exact JSON from your question you can use this:
val list: List<Root2> = listOf(
    Root2(id = "kategorie1", caption = "A", features = listOf(
        Feature(id = 1, name = "A1", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 10, time = "10 AM"), Schedule(id = 11, time = "12 AM"))),
        Feature(id = 2, name = "A2", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 10, time = "10 AM"), Schedule(id = 11, time = "12 AM"))),
    )),
    Root2(id = "kategorie2", caption = "B", features = listOf(
        Feature(id = 3, name = "B1", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 21, time = "10 AM"))),
        Feature(id = 4, name = "B2", rotation = "0", schedules = listOf(Schedule(id = 23, time = "10 AM"), Schedule(id = 25, time = "12 AM"))),
    )),
)

val json: String = Json {
    prettyPrint = true
    prettyPrintIndent = "  "
}.encodeToString(list)


To set up the kotlinx.serialization library add this to the respective sections of your version catalog:
[versions]
kotlinxSerializationJson = "1.7.3"

[libraries]
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "kotlinxSerializationJson" }

[plugins]
kotlin-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Then add the plugin to your gradle files' plugins block. In your root gradle file:
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization) apply false

In your module gradle file:
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)

And finally add the dependency to your module gradle file's dependencies block:
implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)

After a gradle sync everything should be set up and ready to use.
